# Check if D.userid exists in a directory shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

We assume the current directory has a number of directories named D.userid, each of which contains submitted Java files. How to detect if there is D.userid present in a directory? What should be the code. I dont this mine is rite

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d "$D.*" ]
then


else
    echo "no .java file(s) submitted"
    exit    
fi
done
```

Comment: The only thing that's wrong is that you should use an `else` for the negative case rather than a second, embedded `if`.

Comment: check my new code? does it check if D.id exists?

Answer (score 1):

Since you assume there are files, and only want to be informed that there are none, I think this is reasonable:

```
ls D.* > /dev/null       # try to list the files. we don't need output
return=$?                # save the return value of ls just in case
if [ $return -ne 0 ];    # compare it to 0 (success)
then
    echo "No files."
fi
```

`ls` returns 2 if the files are not found, so if you want you can use that directly. Of course, it doesn't check that they are directories, but it's just another way.

Comment: can you help with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436607/need-to-create-a-output-directory-with-result-equals-name-after-symbol